# double spend script is not working!

Tags: transaction, node, double-spending, cli-wallet

I'm running a private tangle network (GoShimmer 1.7.2) using Docker https://goshimmer.docs.iota.org/tooling/docker_private_network.html

I want to try a double spend. there is a script to do that in the tools:
https://github.com/iotaledger/goshimmer/tree/develop/tools/double-spend

It requests successfully funds from the faucet, but after that an error accrue in those lines:

```
            // issue the tx
            resp, err2 := clients[i].PostTransaction(tx.Bytes())
            if err2 != nil {
                fmt.Println("ERROR ISSUE TRANSACTION"); // err2
                fmt.Println(err);
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(resp.TransactionID);
```

[image]

Expected:

```
        fmt.Println(resp.TransactionID)
        fmt.Printf("issued conflict transaction %s\n", conflictingMsgIDs[i])
```

Comment: Just to make sure: When you do a single transaction, you don't see the error, but only when you are trying to double-spend? Are your nodes sufficiently "slowly" connected so that the double spend can actually get through without the second node already having seen the first transaction?

Comment: yes doing transaction (transfer funds between addresses) using cli-wallet works. when i try the script, the address get also funds from the faucet. I don't think the transaction is getting through or getting accepted, because resp is also 'nil' @mihi

Comment: So when you have not yet tested single spend via script, I would suggest to reduce the script to single spend transactions and make sure that they work, before working on double spend.